# JavaScript - using addEventListener instead of inline "onchange" with select menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use "addEventListener" instead of an inline "onchange".

Something is wrong with my approach. How do I use the "addEventListener" correctly?

https://jsfiddle.net/gdfe2ynL/1/

```html
<select id="feedbackCategory" onchange="logvalue(this.value)">
          <option value="" selected>Choose a category</option>
          <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
          <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
        </select>
        
        <select id="feedbackCategory2">
          <option value="" selected>Choose a category</option>
          <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
          <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
        </select>
    
 <script>
    
    function logvalue(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }   
    
    document.getElementById("feedbackCategory2").addEventListener("change", logvalue(this.value));
    
 </script>
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the programmatic listener, the event comes through as `event`, the element is `event.target` and the value of that element is `event.target.value`. It's easier for this kind of thing to group the elements together with a common attribute, like `class` and then apply the listener to each one of them via `querySelectorAll` and a `forEach` loop

```js
function logvalue(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value + ' selected from the #' + event.target.id + ' element')
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".fbselect").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", logvalue))

})
```

```html
<select class='fbselect' id="feedbackCategory">
  <option value="" selected>Choose a category</option>
  <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
  <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
</select>

<select class='fbselect' id="feedbackCategory2">
  <option value="" selected>Choose a category</option>
  <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
  <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed! Thank you